# What does it mean that "Java methods are metadata"?

Tags: java, methods

I was reading [this explanation](https://javascriptweblog.wordpress.com/2010/07/06/function-declarations-vs-function-expressions/) on functions in JavaScript, and it had the following statement which confused me:

> Function Declarations feel like they were intended to mimic Java style method declarations but Java methods are very different animals. In JavaScript functions are living objects with values. Java methods are just metadata storage.

What does it mean that "Java methods are just metadata storage"? I understand that JavaScript functions are just a type of object like in Python. But how are methods handled internally in Java?

Comment: Java and JavaScript are completely different, and unrelated languages. Any sentence that confuses the two languages should be taken with a... pile of salt.

Comment: @JBNizet The statement in the article is contrasting the differences between the two different languages. It isn't confusing them. However, the author's meaning by this statement is entirely unclear to me.

Comment: Maybe you should ask the author what "Java methods are just metadata storage" is supposed to mean. It doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: @JBNizet "Function Declarations feel like they were intended to mimic Java style method declarations but Java methods are very different animals. In JavaScript functions are living objects with values. Java methods are just metadata storage." To clarify, the preceding statements make it clear that the author understands the difference between Java and JavaScript.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice Reading it, I come to the same conclusion: I have no idea of what the author means.

Comment: You will have to ask the author what they mean by this statement. The terminology they are using is non-standard.

Comment: The terminology is standard but it is being misused, or abused, to the point of meaninglessness. The only sense I can make out do it is that JavaScript functions are ('first-class') objects where Java methods allegedly aren't. But they are.